# How to access EmbeddedItem attachment in Outlook VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

I am using Outlook 2010 and the QuickSteps only allow to create a Task from an email with the email body copied to the task body or with the email as attachment.

I already have a small script which is called when a new task object is added to the task directory.
If I have a an email attachment to the task I would like to copy its body to the task body.

```
Public WithEvents OlItems As Outlook.Items

Sub Application_Startup()
    Set OlItems = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderTasks).Items
End Sub

Sub OlItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    Dim obApp As Application

    If Item.Class = olTask Then
        Item.Status = olTaskDeferred

        If Item.Attachments.Item(1).Type = olEmbeddeditem Then
            Dim attachment As attachment
            Set attachment = Item.Attachments.Item(1)
            Debug.Print (attachment.FileName)
            '???: Item.body = attachment.body
        End If

    Item.Save
    End If

    Set obApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

The attachment is of type olEmbeddedItem. 
I can't figure out how to open/read from it?

Is this possible? My goal is to have both body and email attachment in the task item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outlook Object Model will not let you directly access embedded message attachments  - if you were using C++ or Delphi, you could use Extended MAPI to open the embedded message attachment using `IAttach::OpenProperty(PR_ATTACH_DATA_OBJ, IID_IMessage)`.

The only workaround is to save the attachment as an MSG file (`Attachment.SaveAsFile`) and open it using `Application.Session.OpenSharedItem`

Or you can use [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author - it wraps Extended MAPI and can be used from any language) and do something like the following:

```
RDOSession session = new RDOSession();
RDOMail msg = (RDOMail)session.GetRDOObjectFromOutlookObject(YourOutlookMailItem);
foreach (RDOAttachment att in msg.Attachments)
{
    if (att.Type == rdoAttachmentType.olEmbeddedItem)
    {
        RDOMail embeddedMsg = att.EmbeddedMsg;
        ProcessEmbeddedMessage(embeddedMsg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I managed to execute the macro at a different state which gives me a chance to create the task from scratch and add subject and attachment there.
But you answer is still correct, as it is not possible with VBA alone.